# Trader interview online math assessment question 2

Tags: probability, standard-deviation

Suppose an NFL team is average. They play 16 games(assume no ties). Two quants are trying to estimate the number of wins.

One quant assumes a probability of 1/2 of winning each game. Using this assumption, he calculates the standard deviation SD1 of the number of wins.

The second quant assumes a probability of 0.6 for home games and 0.4 for away games. Using this assumption she calculates the standard deviation SD2.

What is the ratio of SD1/SD2 to two decimals?

Well my experience and exposure with binomials is very limited so what i thought which i am aware it is wrong is that 0.5 * 16 would be 8 wins from quant 1 and then 0.6 * 8 = 4.8 but there is no such thing 4.8 wins so 4 and 0.4 * 8 = 3.2 so 3 wins for a total of 7 wins for quant 2 which would result in a 8/7 ratio.

Solution 2 i tried was SD1= sq.root of 16 * 1/2 * (1- 1/2) which is 1 and the same for SD2 which gives me 0.96 for a SD1/SD2 = 1/0.96

Comment: Are you sincerely asking how to calculate two standard deviations from two binomial RVs and then take their quotient?

Comment: Yeah, sorry if i offended you buddy. Guess i m not at your level in math

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 guess everyone in here learned everything from birth.

Comment: well i am sorry my comment came off as condescending when i didn't mean it to be. Let me try to fix that: what did you try and where are you stuck on this problem? Hint: the standard deviation of any RV is the square root of its variance. Do you know what the variance of a binomial RV is?

Comment: i learned binomial random variables in high school, forgot about them, and relearned them in college—like many average math students like me. If you are not going to explain what you are stuck on, nobody is going to be able to help you without spoon-feeding the answer to you.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 to be honest with you i never expected that. Just thought it would be better if i asked the question without my answer. I m completely new to the site and still learning about how to post. but i will edit now

Comment: welcome to the site :) https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question .

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 thanks a lot for that. will keep in mind for future reference. and sorry for the whole misunderstanding

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 btw because i am actually interested could you tell me if there's a handbook i could get or download so i can learn/review all of these concepts of probability/statistics?

Comment: certainly, but i need to know your background. Are you looking for an elementary probability text or a calculus based probability text?

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 calculus probability. Engineer in the making :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are mismatching your parameters.
You have two binomial variables $X$ and $Y$ both with parameters $n,p$ and $n,r$. Here $n=16$, $p=0.5$ and $r=0.6$.

Then, recall the expected number of games is the number of trials multiplied by chance of success: $np=8$ and $nr=9.6$. It is ok to have a decimal there. While you can't win $9.6$ games exactly you will, **on average**, win $9.6$ games (think about the arithmetic average of $0$ and $1$ for an analogy: it is $0.5$).

Next, recall the variance is $npq$ where $q$ is the chance of failure, that is, $q=1-p$ and for your second RV, you have $nrs$ where $s=r-1$.

Can you finish from here? Comment for clarifications.

*Edit:*
I have misread one aspect. Let me recap. Quant1 thinks the number of games won ought to be modeled as $X\sim B(n,p)$ with $n=16$ and $p=0.5$. Quant2 thinks it should be $W=Y+Z$ where $Y\sim B(a,r)$, $Z\sim B(h,s)$, and where $a,h$ are the number of away games and home games, so that $a+h=n$ and $r=0.4$ and $s=0.6$ are chances of winning away and home games, respectively. We assume $Y$ and $Z$ are independent. Then the variance of $W$ is the sum of the variances of $Y$ and $Z$, but we know these since they are binomial, as discussed above. Thus, in the general form, the SD of number of games won in Quant2's model is $\sqrt{ar+hs}$. So the general form for the desired ratio is 
$$\frac{\sqrt{np}}{\sqrt{ar+hs}},$$
Which will only give you a numerical answer if you *know* what $a$ and $h$ are (I assume, they want the case $a=h$).

Comment for any clarifications.

[Requested free text on probability](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/amsbook.mac.pdf)

Comment: Shouldn't for quant 2 since it gives 0.6 probability for home games and 0.4 for away do two different calculations or am i missing something here?Thanks for the rest of the solution which actually made much more sense

Comment: @El_Greco yes you are right. I misread that as different chance of success not as different chances depending on home vs away. You will then have 3 RVs in total, 2 are from Quant 2, one counting the home game wins, and the other away game wins, with the appropriate parameters. Ill edit soon.

Comment: @El_Greco i have added an update to cover what i had originally misread. I am not sure if you get notified so im commenting just in case.

Comment: thanks again for your input. However i did the math and i get a ratio of 1 which does not seem like the right answer. Would you mind if you had the time to do the calculations and let me know if you had the same result?

Comment: @El_Greco I can indeed confirm that calculation but let's go further and see why that is happening. Assuming $a=h$ we have $a=n/2$ and as the question is posed, the chance of winning at away games is 1 less than the chance of winning home games, i.e. $r=1-s$. Thus, using these we simplify $\sqrt{ar+hs}=\sqrt{a(r+s)}=\sqrt{n/2}$ and this holds regardless of the actual value of of $s$, the chance of winning a home game, due to the relationships $a=h$ and $r=1-s$. Now, when $p=1/2$, the numerator will equal $\sqrt{n/2}$ but this is equal to the above denominator! Hence the ratio is $=1$.

Comment: Ok thank you so much for taking your time to answer this question for me being so thorough. I appreciate your actions and attitude. Have a good one, see you around :)

Comment: @El_Greco no problem, glad to help. Feel free to ping me in the future and Sorry about the tone of my first comment, i now see it is not what i had intended at all. Also, there is a way to accept answers on this site marking the question as "answered". I believe it is the check mark near the up/down voting arrows on my answer, if you will :)